# how to remove header from stack navigator in drawer navigator in react version 6.x

Tags: rxjs, react-native, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-drawer

> this is my stack navigator
> [image]

> this is my drawer navigator
> [image]

> the problem is my Drawer navigtor header in stack navigator screen 2 - [name='Details',component='Anote'],
> I want to remove the drawer navigator from the below picture [ie. one with the title=[Notes Maker]]

[image]

Comment: did you fix it? i am facing the same issue in React navigation 6

Comment: yes but i had to make it manually. one nav is manually made

Answer (score 5):

- if you remove header of **stack.Navigator** use the **screenOptions** attribute and make **false** the **headerShown** :

  ```
  screenOptions={{headerShown:false}}
  ```
- but is you want to remove the header of **Drawer.Navigator** use the options attribute and make **false** the **headerShown**:

  ```
  options={{headerShown: false}}
  ```

Answer (score 2):

well if you remove `options={{ headerShown: true}}` from `<Drawer.screem ... >` tag it will works because according to documentation: headerShown#
Whether to show or hide the header for the screen. The header is not shown by default. Setting this to true shows the header.

Comment: if I do that it will be hidden for both the stack screen, I want to hide it in stack screen -2 [component = Anote] only